# Generate SQL with Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

Suppose I have a database diagram (Entity Relationship) in its version number `57`, then I modify the diagram creating version `58` (I add 2 tables), I need Workbench to generate a file with extension "sql" with the code sql difference between version 57 and 58, that is, a file with the code of the 2 tables created recently, I know it is possible but I do not know how to do it.

I was doing tests in Workbench, and I was able to modify the diagram and export the SQL file, but it absolutely exported all the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a diff between 2 models, but you can create one from the model version 57 and an SQL file exported from your model version 58. Use "Synchronize with any source" for that:

Open your model version 57. Once loaded go to the `Database` menu where you can find the synchronization entries. Launching the any source sync will show you a wizard where you can select the SQL for version 58 and a target (DB server or SQL script) which receives the SQL statements to transform version 57 to 58.

Comment: Ok, then this are the steps.
1) Open Entity-Relation (Diagram) version 57
2) Database->Synchronize With Any Source
3) In the first option I need select the diagram 57, the second option is sql file from version 58, and the last option is a destination file with all changes

It's correct?

Comment: The generated code converts a database 58 into a 57?

Comment: The other way around. The model is the source (version 57). Then you compare that to the sql from 58, which should give you a diff script to go from 57 to 58.